# using 1 numeric option for 2 different functions in the same loop

Tags: python, python-3.6

its an atm program, option 2 lets user enter a deposit amount but within that deposit option is is another list of options that uses the same numeric values
for other options.

```
if verify_pin(pin):    
  print("           Welcome to MCC ATM           ")
  print("****************************************")
  print("*   1. Balance inquiry                 *")
  print("*   2. Deposit                         *")    
  print("*   3. Withdrawal                      *")    
  print("*   4. Transfer Funds                  *")    
  print("*   5. History of Last 5 Transactions  *")    
  print("*   6. Exit                            *")    
  print("****************************************")

  option = int(input())    
  if option == 6:        
    print("*Exited Program*")       
    break    
  elif option < 1:            
    print("***Invalid Entry***")    
  elif option > 6:           
    print("***Invalid Entry***")    
  elif option ==1: 
    #HERE YOU CAN SEE THAT OPTION 1 PRINTS THE BALANCE OF BOTH  ACCOUNTS
    print("Checkings Balance: $" + format(checkings,'.2f'))            
    print("Savings balance: $" + format(savings,'.2f'))    
  elif option == 2:
    #BUT HERE I NEED IT TO ALLOW THEM TO DEPOSIT INTO THE CHECKINGS ACOUNT WITHOUT PRINTING THE BALANCES
    print("*********************************************")            
    print("*  1. Checking Account                      *") 
    print("*  2. Savings Account                       *")  
    print("*  3. Go Back To Main Menu                  *")              
    print("*********************************************")
```

Comment: Could you please provide the loop.

Comment: while tries < 4 and the reason for that is tries = 1 in the beginning for the pin entry, and adds 1 each try, and if the user exceeds 3 tries, tries = 4 and wont execute the while loop. hope you understand

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read about the [Finite State machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine).

In short, initially, your program should be in `main-menu` state. after you enter (2), the state should change to `deposit` and request further user input. At that moment, when the user enters (1), you should ignore the `main-menu` if/else block and instead check the `deposit` block.

thus a pseudo code solution using your code as a base would look something like:

```
while (app_running):
  if verify_pin(pin):
    if app_state == 'main-menu':
      # print main menu
      # request input
      # process input in the main menu if/else case
    if app_state == 'deposit':
      # print deposit menu
      # request input
      # process input in the deposit if/else case
    ...
```

Comment: what would define for app_running for the to work properly? says app_running not defined

Comment: The `while(app_running): ` should be defined somewhere above your initial example. It is the main loop of your application, ensuring that it will be requesting user input until the end of user-machine interaction. To simplify it for a toy example, you can simply define it as `while(True) for an endless loop.

Comment: Additionally, `app_state` is also not defined in this example. It should be initiated with the default state of your application, most probably as `app_state = main-menu`

Comment: Hey i wanted to add on to this to say that your method worked perfectly, thanks for giving me insight.